# Recargar DIV automaticamente laravel ajax

Tags: laravel, ajax

Intento recargar los datos con una frecuencia de XXX segundos.

Lo que estoy haciendo es enviando a traves de peticion ajax que me pida los datos al controlador, este los devuelve y en las herramientas de desarrollador se muestran los datos que retorna correctamente, sin embargo la vista no se actualiza.

No manejo javascript, salvo para un par de cosas, y por lo tanto no me aclaro mucho con el tema de ajax, lo entiendo, se lo que hace pero a la hora de implementarlo me bloqueo facilmente.

el codigo del controlador es el siguiente:

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = Listing::where('status','=', 1)->with(['offer', 'recieve', 'user'])->get();

        $this->listings = json_decode($data);

        return view('listings.index', ['listings' => $this->listings]);
    }
```

La parte de javascript es muy simple y es este:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            sendRequest();
        }, 3000);
    });


    function sendRequest(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "listings",
            type: "GET",
            success:
                function(result){
                console.log(result);
                },
            complete: function() {
                
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

En la foto enseño como se muestra la pantalla de la vista y como se ve en herramientas de desarrollador. al hacer cambio en base de datos en herramientas de desarrollador lo enseña al instante.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Gracias
```

Comment: y como quieres que la vista se actualice? que quieres hacer? cambiar el color de un boton, llenar una tabla, esconder/mostrar elementos?, tienes que ser mas especifico.

Comment: Lo que quiero es que los datos que me estan llegando con la peticion refrescarlos en la vista, que se actualice, pero solo recargar el div en cuestion y no toda la pagina, No es una tabla como tal, para tablas uso datatables pero este no es el caso. Los datos llegan y desde herr desarrollo se ven pero el div no he conseguido refrescar el div en la vista como tal

Comment: La ventaja con ajax es que no es necesario actualizar o resfrescar la vista para ver los cambios, esto permite que si la peticion fue exitosa podemos tomar un elemento (Tabla,Div,Button..etc) y podemos modificarlo, esconderlo, eliminarlo sin necesidad de actualizar la vista completa.

Comment: Entonces no quiieres "refrescar la vista" quieres actualizar un `<div>` con la peticion, el ejemplo que escribir abajo va a servir solo tienes que cambiar la lógica dependiendo lo que quieras hacer con tu `<div>`

Comment: Gracias David por tu tiempo, le echare un vistazo para implementarlo, y revisare la documentación que me pasas.

Answer (score 1):

Hola adrian te recomiendo que a la próxima seas mas especifico con lo que quieres lograr, y también que muestres la estructura de la información que te llega a la vista, voy a mostrarte un ejemplo muy básico de como podrías manejar una petición con ajax, espero que logres entender un poco y te sirva.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        sendRequest();
    }, 3000);
});

//Hacemos la peticion ajax
function sendRequest(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "listings",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(response){
            //Aca pasa cuando la operación fue exitosa
            //Lo primero seria comprobar como vienen la response
              if(response.length){
              //Esto en caso de que la respuesta venga vacia, response=[]
              //podrias mostrar un mensaje de que no se encontro informacion
              //Obtener un elemento por id para setearle un texto
              $("#MiEjemplo").text("No se encontro informacion")
              }else{
                  //Aca si tiene informacion la respuesta
                  foreach(let list in response){
                      //No se como es tu estructura asi que esto es una suposicion
                      //suponmgamos que quieres llenar una tabla con la info
                      //Aca recorremos la informacion y creamos la estructura de la tabla
                      let contenidoParaTabla = `<tr>
                                                <td> ${list.id}</td>
                                                <td> ${list.nombre}</td>
                                                </tr>`
                  }
                  //Aca mediante el id de la tabla le agregamos el contenido creado
                  $("#miTablaDeEjemplo").append(contenidoParaTabla)
              }       
            },
        error: function(error) {
            //Aca pasa si es que fallo la peticion
            //Es recomendable mostrar el error para saber que paso
            //Puede ser un error codigo 404, 400, 500, 401..etc
            console.log("ha ocurrido un error",error)
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

Aca la documentacion de ajax [doc ajax](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)
Lectura recomendada de jquery [doc jquery](https://api.jquery.com/)
Para el manejo del DOM con jquery te recomiendo buscar informacion de `append()`, `html()`, `text()`, `empty()` (Metodos de `jquery`)

Comment: Gracias @David081, Revisare tu ejemplo y  en cuanto a lo que quiero lograr lo explico asi. se hacen las peticiones a la ruta, esto lo hace, me trae la info que cuando pongo herramientas de dasarrollador el div que contiene esa info se actualiza sin problema , la cuestion es que el div en la vista propiamente dicha no se actualiza. Actualizar el DIV para rerescar esa info cada x tiempo.

Comment: Bueno quizá no se actualiza porque en la petición ajax que agregaste en la pregunta no tienen nada mas que un `console.log()`, falta que obtengas la información y manipules el DOM dependiendo lo que quieras hacer